# Can anyone help me with galleries and post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, gallery

Hi i'm opening a blog and i am using custom post types. I don't know if i'm doing this wrong or right.

Check out wetpaint.com

For example they have a page for every show that they cover, i don't know if it's custom post types they are using or taxonomies.

They have wetpaint.com/pretty-little-liars and for a photo gallery they have wetpaint.com/pretty-little-liars/photos and wetpaint.com/pretty-little-liars/photos/title-of-the-gallery-post

I created a custom post type but how do i get it to link like mysite.com/custom-post-type/photos or mysite.com/custom-post-type/videos

or am i doing it wrong? Should it be a custom post type or are they using pages.

I have googled this for hours and still haven't found a solution

Comment: You can try using pages and nested pages, but this site don't seems using WordPress at all.

Answer (score 0):

Wetpaint isn't using Wordpress.

If you're only planning on doing this for 10 or so shows, from your example, pages and nested pages might be a good option.

Otherwise, there are several ways to go about it. Here's one:

From your example, you could use "Pretty Little Liars" as the term in one custom taxonomy (the taxonomy would be tv shows), and then attach a second custom taxonomy for the type of content that it is (e.g. photos, videos, etc. would be the terms in that second taxonomy).

If you don't want to code this out from scratch, the excellent Types plugin for Wordpress might help as well (I've done it both ways, and I much prefer using the plugin).